# Jekyll Liquid If-Or-Condition is False, even though one of the two conditions should return true

Tags: jekyll, liquid

To summarize, I have an array including several arrays that look like this:
`[0, 1, 2, 3, {'key': 'example', 'id': 0}]`.

I have a loop that looks like this:

```
{% for arr in array %} // Array including the array I showed above
  {% for item in arr %} // Array of pattern I showed above

    {% if item.key == key and item.id == id %}
      If-1 True
    {% else %}
      If-2 False
    {% endif %}

    {% if (elem == key and item == id) or (item.key == key and item.id == id ) %}
      If-2 True
    {% else %}
      If-2 False
    {% endif %}

  {% endloop %}
{% endloop %}
```

As you can see, the second If-Statement includes the condition of the first If statement, as well as a second condition with an `or` between. As I am understanding from my past experience in programming, this should mean that if either of the two conditions are `true`, the whole If-Statement should be `true`.

However this is not the case here. The first Statement will return the `If-1 True` String when the second Statement still returns the `If-2 False` String.

Why is this the case? Does `or` work differently in Liquid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing `)` bracket on the `or` line at the end. That might solve it:

```
{% if (elem == key and item == id) or (item.key == key and item.id == id) %}
```

I've had issues like this in the past (years ago), and worked around them by assigning each side of the `or` to a separate variable first. No idea why but this might help:

```
{% assign a = elem == key and item == id %}
{% assign b = item.key == key and item.id == id %}
{% if a or b %}
```

Comment: i did miss the bracket, unfortunately that issue was only in the example code i provided here... the bracket exists on my real code, yet the `or` still doesn't work
i'll give the second workaround a try tho!